# How to Add & Remove multiple selected list values to another selected list in on click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I stuck here & I'm new to JavaScript. I have four select list box totally. Here I select the first three select list box values. After selecting the values, I want to store those values in the fourth select list box in on click(Add Category) & when clicking the remove category button, those values should be removed.

[image]

```
<select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<p class="text-center color-red">You can add up to 10 categories</p>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category">
<select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="5">
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save</strong> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
    var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
    var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();
    $('#add-category').click(function() {
        $(
            '.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2'
        ).each(function() {
            $('#selected-lst-values').append($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#selected-lst-values').append($(this).val());` is trying to append a string to a `<select>` field. Try something like:

```
$('#selected-lst-values').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
```

Depending on how you want the buttons to work, you can do either of these:

```
//Remove the values selected in the top 3
$('#remove-category').click(function() {
    $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').each(function() {
        $('#selected-lst-values')
               .find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"')
               .remove();
    });
});


//Remove the values selected in the bottom
$('#remove-category').click(function() {
    $('#selected-lst-values').find('option:selected').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Ethan22. Adding values to list works well. But, I want to remove those selected values when click on "Remove Category" button. Is it possible?

Comment: That depends on how you want the interface to work. When you click on "Remove Category", do you want to remove the option you have selected in the bottom `<select>` field, or the options selected in the top 3 `<select>` fields.